# SQL Server DATE_DIFF INTERVAL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, sql-server-2014

Hello what am i doing wrong??

iam trying to show r.reizen with a date difference from r.vertrek of 1 day

can someone help

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.vertrek, b.reiscode, r.bestemming, r.dagen, r.prijs
FROM boekingen b
INNER JOIN reizen r ON b.reiscode = r.reiscode
WHERE b.reiscode <> 'JH10' 
AND ((b.vertrek BETWEEN 
(SELECT MIN(DATE_SUB(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM boekingen WHERE          reiscode = 'JH10') AND 
(SELECT MIN(DATE_ADD(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM boekingen WHERE                reiscode = 'JH10')) OR 
(b.vertrek BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(DATE_SUB(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM            boekingen WHERE reiscode = 'JH10') 
AND (SELECT MAX(DATE_ADD(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM boekingen  WHERE reiscode = 'JH10')))
ORDER BY 1
```

---

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

Comment: which DB. datetime is product specific

Comment: please add source data sample and expected result

Comment: Do you want to add/subtract date in MYSQL or SQL server?
DATE_SUB and DATE_ADD are functions in mysql, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If it's sql server, it's not mySql. those are 2 different products.

Comment: It's in SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You're using the MySQL syntax for DATE_SUB with the Microsoft SQL Server engine. This is a Microsoft SQL error, for people who are guessing....

```
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
```

The date function you're using is:

```
DATE_SUB(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
DATE_ADD(vertrek, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) FROM
```

The Microsoft variants are:

```
DATEADD(DAY, -1, vertrek)
DATEADD(DAY, 1, vertrek)
```

Accepteer dit antwoord en punten toekennen , bedankt.

Comment: While correct, the last sentence in dutch seems a bit out of place.

Comment: I know. I'm a sucker for a Google-translate joke when the mood hits, and despite knowing it's transposed a few words, I thought I'd let it stand ^_^

Comment: how did you know iam dutch?

Comment: Anyone who's been to an airport will recognize vertrek.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to fixing the date arithmetic, your query would be much easier to read without the subqueries in the `WHERE` clause.  It is easy enough to move the summaries to the `FROM` clause:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT b.vertrek, b.reiscode, r.bestemming, r.dagen, r.prijs
  FROM boekingen b INNER JOIN
       reizen r
       ON b.reiscode = r.reiscode CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MIN(vertrek) as minv, MAX(vertrek) as maxv
        FROM boekingen
        WHERE reiscode = 'JH10'
       ) bm
  WHERE b.reiscode <> 'JH10' AND
        b.vertrek BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, minv) and DATEADD(day, 1, minv) AND
        b.vertrek BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, maxv) AND DATEADD(day, 1, maxv)
  ORDER BY b.vertek;
```

Comment: thanks for the effort. but i never worked with a cross join

Comment: when iam executing this query its not showing anything